# How to get averages from .txt file and display into 2 columns, names & averages

Tags: python, function, loops, file

My assignment requires me to open a .txt file of athletes and 4 of their scores, I need to average their scores and display it next to their name in two columns, using loops and functions.

example
name    average

But I don't know how to separate their name from the numbers and then get it to loop for the whole file. This is as far as I've gotten. We haven't learned lists yet.

```
def openReadFile(golf_scores):
    #open the file
    infile = open(golf_scores, 'r')
    #read the files contents

    ##displayData(player, average)  ##I need to call this at some point
     
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
 
    line = infile.readline()
        
        
    infile.close()

def displayData(player, average):
    #display player name next to average score
    print(f'{player}\t\t\t  {average}')
```

Comment: When you do `for line in infile:` you are looping over the lines. No need for a `line = infile.readline()`. You'll have to give us more details about this text file. Is it always "firstname lastname score"? Then try `line.split(" ")` to get the parts.

Comment: please show how the data was structured in the text file

Comment: The .txt file has the name on one line and each score on its own line. each athlete has 5 lines of data, their name and four scores.

Answer (score 0):

The way you achieve this will depend on how the data are organised in your input file.

If the layout is like this:

```
name 1 2 3 4
name 3 4 2 1
```

i.e., a single token representing the athlete's name followed by some scores then:

```
with open("golf_scores.txt") as scores:
    for row in scores:
        name, *nums = row.split()
        average = sum(map(float, nums)) / len(nums)
        print(f"{name} {average:.2f}")
```

**Note:**

The number of scores on each line doesn't matter except that there must be at least one

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to add that. first and last name are on a line, and each score is on its own line. Each athlete has 5 lines of data: name, score, score, score, score.